# Is it possible to return a list with generic type in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generic-type-argument

There is the following function:

```
import pdfplumber
from pdfplumber.page import Page
def searchFromFile(path:str,keyword:str) -> list[Page]:
  with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    result = [Page]
    for page in pdf.pages:
        pageText = page.extract_text()
        if pageText != None and keyword in pageText:
            result.append(page)
    return result
```

In order to be more accurate, I defined the returned `list` with a generic type like in Java, i.e.`list[Page]`, but it didn't work and got error:

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Question: Is is possible at all to define the returned `list` with generic type?

Comment: That should work. What error did you get? Have you already defined the `Page` class?

Comment: [Support for type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics)

Comment: @Barmar I pasted the whole function, so the `Page` is from `pdfplumber`

Comment: You need Python 3.9 or later to use `list` as a generic type.

Comment: @chepner I have only Python 3.7. As Python is not backward-compatible, I dont want to use 3.9 yet

Comment: Then don't use `list[Page]`; use `typing.List[Page]`.

Comment: Use `from typing import List`, and then annotate it as `List[Page]` rather than `list[Page]`. It's a solution that works for Python <=3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in `list` wasn't made a generic type until Python 3.9. In earlier versions, you'll have to use `List` (from the `typing` module) instead.

```
from typing import List


def searchFromFile(path:str, keyword:str) -> List[Page]:
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried with this, and it indeed works :)